# Pass data-attr in Materialize's modal (leanModal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am using Materialize framework in my rails app. I have this element that launch a modal on click:

```
<div data-target="modal1" class="modal-trigger" data-code="<%=code%>">lalala</div>
```

I want to catch the data-code in js and save it to variable. I've done something like this following the official documentation:

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
  ready: function() { 
  var a = $(this).attr("data-code");
  },
}
```

The variable "a" is undefined. How I can pass data-attr in Materialize modal? What is the best way? Thanks.

Update: I'd like to then display the value of data-code in the modal. This is the code:

```
  <div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>The Code</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Update1: I eventually solved it with clickOn method and append the data attr to a particular div but wondering if it is possible to pass it also through modal.

Comment: Check what is finally rendered in your markup as you use inline code..
This should work if `this` refers to this div.

Comment: This is referring to the modal I think. The data attr is not forwarded to this function. Not sure how I can accomplish it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in chrome dev tools here `var a = $(this).attr("data-code");` and inspect what "this" refers to. You can also use `.prop("data-code")`